# What do parentheses at the kind level mean?

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, type-kinds

I understand the following kinds:

```
String :: *
[] :: * -> *
(->) :: * -> * -> *
(,) :: * -> * -> *
```

But what does this kind mean and what type might it represent?

```
? :: (* -> *) -> *
```

Comment: Here is a contrived example: `data IntContainer f = IC (f Int)`. Then, I can have values like `IC [1,2,3]` or `IC (Data.Set.fromList [1,2,3])`. Note that `IntContainer :: (* -> *) -> *`.

Comment: That you pass it a higher-kinded type as first type parameter

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: `* -> *` isn’t a higher-kinded type. `(* -> *) -> *` is—just as a higher-order function takes a function as a parameter, a higher-kinded type takes a type constructor as a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`? :: (* -> *) -> *` means that if you give to `?` something of kind `* -> *`, you'll get back a type (something of kind `*`). Let's take a concrete example:

```
newtype IntContainer f = IC { getContainer :: f Int }
```

This is meant to contain `Int`s. I can make `IntContainer`s with lists, or sets, or anything I want (of kind `* -> *`) as the underlying data structure. The thing is that `f` isn't a type here - it needs to have another type applied to it before it is a type. So: `IntContainer` needs to have something applied to it, which in turn needs a type applied to it.

```
ghci> :kind IntContainer
IntContainer :: (* -> *) -> *
```

I can make concrete types by applying things of kind `* -> *` to `IntContainer`:

```
ghci> ic1 = IC [1,2,3]
ic1 :: IntContainer []                           -- [] :: * -> *
ghci> ic2 = IC (Data.Set.fromList [1,2,3])
ic2 :: IntContainer Set                          -- Set :: * -> *
ghci> ic3 = IC (Data.Sequence.fromList [1,2,3])
ic3 :: IntContainer Seq                          -- Seq :: * -> *
```

Comment: Higher kinded types that take type constructors as parameters. It is obvious to me now. In my defense I can only say that kind annotations such as `(* -> *) -> *` have a fairly high level of abstraction. Thank you!